# LIRC can not load conf file, irsend returns "unknown remote"

Tags: gpio, pi-5

Pi-5 GPIO
I am getting error while sending irsend command.'

```
$$$: irsend SEND_ONCE monitor menu
unknown remote "monitor"
Error running command: Input/output error
```

in my lircd.conf:

```
include "lircd.conf.d/*.conf"
```

And I have my conf files in that directory which are `aircon.lircd.conf` and `monitor.lircd.conf`.

in my monitor.lircd.conf file:

```
begin remote
    
  name monitor
  flags RAW_CODES
  eps  30
  aeps 100
  gaps 19991

  begin raw_codes
    name menu
    **numbers**
  
  end raw_codes
end remote
```

I also tried `irsend list "" ""` but nothing found, maybe conf files are not loaded correctly? I tried to restart lirc and reboot raspi several times.

How can I fix this?